# VS Code Run extension - no output shown from running program

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, deno, vscode-code-runner

Recently I have tried Deno and since it has native TypeScript support, I thought it would be neat to use it as a "typescript runner". For example in Node you would write `node server.js` and in Deno would be like `deno run -A server.ts` and all of this in the code runner extension.

In vscode settings.json :

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {    
    "javascript": "node",
    "typescript": "cd $dir && deno run -A $fileName"       
}
```

Consider the following ts file "index.ts" :

```
const add = (a: number,b: number):number =>{
    console.log(a+b);
    return a+b;
}

add(1,2);
```

Output when running using the extension :

```
[Running] deno run -A index.ts
[33m3[39m

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.082 seconds
```

Output when using the terminal cmd/powershell :

```
C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop\DenoPJ>deno run -A index.ts
3
```

Any thoughts about why it works inside the terminal and not inside the extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and could reproduce the problem.

When you change the settings under "Run Code configuration" to "Run in Terminal"

[image]

and then run the code again with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>,
VSCode will switch to the Terminal window and you should see:

```
PS C:\Users\jps\source\deno> cd "c:\Users\jps\source\deno\" ; if ($?) { deno run -A index.ts }
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flags to command (depends on your actions of application):

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write --allow-env index.ts
```