# Can I run and debug deno project in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno

I'm new to both typescript and deno, also vscode.

Firstly, I tried it with vscode and failed, and then tried with IntelliJ.
I can run and debug simple .ts file in Intellij with deno plugin.

But I want to know how to do this in vscode(also installed deno plugin, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno).

My settings are...

.vscode/settings.json

```json
{
    "deno.enable": true,
    "deno.lint": true,
    "deno.unstable": true
}
```

.vscode/launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "--unstable",
                "--inspect",
                "--allow-all"
            ],
            "attachSimplePort": 9229
        }
    ]
}
```

Example code

```js
console.log("Hello, World!");
```

When I run this using by `Run without Debugging`
just shows like below image but expected to output `Hello, World!`.
and also seems debugging is not working.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156606/vs-code-run-extension-no-output-shown-from-running-program help?

Comment: @jps It seems using another extension named `Code Runner`.

Comment: with --inspect-brk instead of --inspect, seems debugging is working but Run Without Debugging is still not working(works like debugging). and I think it's not a solution for this.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/557) is looks like the solution for this but I don't understand it's behavior. I think vscode deno plugin is immature compared to intellij deno plugin or somthing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging with `--inspect` does not work for relatively short programs, because it does not wait for the debugger to connect. So when running short programs [the execution finishes before VS Code connects to the inspector](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/557#issuecomment-1009290059). On larger programs this won't be an issue.

For debugging Deno programs that are only a couple of lines long, two options are given [in this thread](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/557):

- Use `--inspect-brk` instead of `--inspect`, this should allow enough time for the debugger to connect and hit breakpoints
- Add some time delay to the code when debugging, for example:

```js
const _sleep = async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}
await _sleep();

console.log("Hello World!"); <-- Here, you could add a breakpoint
```

To Run without Debugging, you can also either add `--inspect-brk`, but you will have to press F5 or click 'Continue' once the session has started. Or, you can use `--inspect` and add the `sleep` function

Comment: I think when I run `Run Without Debugging`, it should run and terminate after things finish but I need to do `Stop Debugging`.  It seems abnormal.

Comment: since deno 1.29, there is a new option `--inspect-wait`, might be a good choice.